# I have a canvas inside a div, and I can't get the sizing right

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, width

I have a canvas inside of a div, and I want the canvas width to be equal to 90% of the div width.

So, for instance:

```
<div id="outerDiv" style="height:750px; width:1000px">
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

And in the .js file when I initiate the canvas, I have:

```
window.onload = init;

// Main initialization function
function init () {
initCanvas();
registerInputListeners();
iPhoneToTop();

}

// Set up the drawing canvas
function initCanvas () {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
// Size canvas
  canvas.width  = $("#outerDiv").width * .9;
  canvas.height = $("#outerDiv").height * .9;
}
```

This isn't working, and is making the canvas really tiny - 2px by 2px.  What am I doing wrong?

I tried console logging the width:

```
 var width = document.getElementById(outerDiv).outerWidth;
 console.log(width);
```

and I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerWidth' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `#outerDiv`. You forgot the `#`. Also I don't think there is `width` or `height` in a jQuery object (assuming `$` is jQuery).

Comment: ah right, sorry. I edited it.

It still doesn't work, though.

Comment: @user3285918 - So `$` is jQuery, right? If it is then `.width` should be `.width()`